# iOS: In App Purchase with buying progress indicator UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I tried several solutions on this board but never successful. What I want is when the user click `Buy Button`, an `UIAlertView` with `UIActivityIndicatorView` appears waiting for the app accessing the app store. But I do not know where to dismiss this `UIAlertView` once the purchase is done. I know that to dismiss a `UIAlertView`, we use: `[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];`

So would you please help me answer two questions:

1) Is my code below OK or any other better to achieve it?

2) Where should I dismiss `UIAlertView` for all cases:

- User accepts  to purchase
- User cancels to purchase
- Purchase is not successful

Following is my code:

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
    UIAlertView *alert;
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions){
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:                   
                 alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"In App Purchase" message: @"Processing your purchase..." delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle: nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
                UIActivityIndicatorView *ind = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
                [ind startAnimating];    
                [alert addSubview: ind];
                [alert show];
                [ind release];
                [alert release];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
                UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:@"Complete"  
                                    message:@"You have bought the full version!"  
                                    delegate:self  
                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil  
                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];  
                [tmp show];  
                [tmp release];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                if (transaction.error.code !=SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
                    UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                        initWithTitle:@"Error"  
                                        message:@"Purchase not successful!"  
                                        delegate:self  
                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil  
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];  
                    [tmp show];  
                    [tmp release];              
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add

```
case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
```

and

```
case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
```

Comment: I did, but when you press `Buy Button` second time, the `UIAlertView` still there forever

Comment: second time? after this you see a "Complete" message?

Comment: I click `Buy Button`, then click 'Cancel' then click 'Buy Button' again, the alert shows forever

Comment: Sure is shown, what u want? When u click in Cancel alert is dismissing?

Comment: I mean, I get stuck there after I click Cancel to purchase and then lick Buy again, no way to get out

Comment: In the - (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction method you can use the following to detect if the user cancelled. if (transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled). You can stop animating your activity indicator here.

Comment: @Tim it seem's you're added comment at my answer, instead at question =)

Comment: @CReaTuS comment was just in relation to DavidNg's question in the comments about no way to get out.

Comment: @Tim if it's true, you missed a "@DavidNg" for notify him