# In app purchase - what to display while waiting for AppStore alertview?

Tags: ios, ios7, app-store, in-app-purchase

After initiating a purchase, it takes a few seconds to for the AppStore alertview to popup before signing in/entering password to confirm purchase.

```
SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

What is recommended to display while this is happening?  At the moment it appears that nothing happens when you press my buy button so it's possible to press it multiple times.

I tried using an UIAlertView but had the same problem as this guy:
[iOS: In App Purchase with buying progress indicator UIActivityIndicatorView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522481/ios-in-app-purchase-with-buying-progress-indicator-uiactivityindicatorview?rq=1)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried displaying a HUD such as SVProgressHUD before you even show anything? I show all activity in status HUDs to let the user know what is happening at all times whenever there is going to be a long process taking place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UIActivityIndicatorView`, in some form. This could be on an alert, a HUD or placed directly onto the table cell (or similar) interface that offered the options to the user. The only thing is that you need to show some activity. Preferably, you should also not block the user from cancelling and doing something else (don't make them want to kill the app if they get bored waiting...).